# LINQ left join datasets and group by

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, outer-join

My data looks like this

1. EOC -  case id, admission, discharge
2. PrinDiag - One per EOC
3. OtherDiag - 0, 1 or many per EOC

   ```
    var results = from dtE in ds.Tables["EOC"].AsEnumerable()
          from dtPD in ds.Tables["PrinDiag"].AsEnumerable()
          .Where(t => dtE.Field<string>("case_id") ==  t.Field<string>("case_id") )
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
          .GroupBy(t => t.Field<string>("case_id"))
          from dtOD in ds.Tables["OtherDiag"].AsEnumerable()
          .Where(t => dtE.Field<string>("case_id") == t.Field<string>("case_id"))                                                 
          .DefaultIfEmpty()
          .GroupBy(t => t.Field<string>("case_id")).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { dtE, dtPD, dtOD };
   ```

I need to create XML from this data.

```
<eocdate>
<EOC>test</EOC>
<admission>22/06/2013</admission>
<patient>
  <facility_patient_id>12345</facility_patient_id>
  <first_name>Matthu</first_name>
  <last_name>MOmmy</last_name>
</patient>
<assessment>
  <newborn_weight />
</assessment>
<principal_diagnosis>
  <principal_diagnosis_code>123   </principal_diagnosis_code>
  <principal_diagnosis_status>0</principal_diagnosis_status>
</principal_diagnosis>
<other_diagnosis>
  <other_diagnosis_code>435   </other_diagnosis_code>
  <other_diagnosis_status>0</other_diagnosis_status>
</other_diagnosis>
<other_diagnosis>
  <other_diagnosis_code>345   </other_diagnosis_code>
  <other_diagnosis_status>0</other_diagnosis_status>
</other_diagnosis>
<other_diagnosis>
  <other_diagnosis_code>1231  </other_diagnosis_code>
  <other_diagnosis_status>0</other_diagnosis_status>
</other_diagnosis>
</eocdate>
```

I am getting "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: row"

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: What line is getting the error.

Comment: When try to create XML using XStreamingElement and save.

Comment: You get the error on a line of code not even shown here?  You have to show us the code with the error dude.

Comment: from dtOD in ds.Tables["OtherDiag"].AsEnumerable()
    .Where(t => dtE.Field<string>("case_id") == t.Field<string>("case_id"))                                                 
     .DefaultIfEmpty()
     .GroupBy(t => t.Field<string>("case_id")).DefaultIfEmpty() I am getting error here.

Comment: did you try moving the default if empty line before the where ?

Comment: no luck, one of the EOC has no OtherDiag, result view shows "dtOD" as null

Comment: Did you consider using the dedicated LINQ-functions for inner and outer joins (`Join` and `GroupJoin`)?